# AngularJS: Injecting services and factories into a non-AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to be able to execute custom external scripts during runtime and give them access to my AngularJS custom services and factories.

The loaded scripts shouldn't be controllers, as I have no interest in linking them to any views.

It should look like that:

1) Load an external script during runtime

- I have my eyes on: https://github.com/urish/angular-load
- This script would have a single non-AngularJS function

2) Inject into that function custom AngularJS services and factories, then execute it.

Is it possible to inject that way?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question as you asked it - yes, you could do something like this.

You could use the `injector` to get a service instance:

```
angular.injector(["Your.Service.Module"]).get("FooSvc");
```

Keep in mind that if your service has other dependencies, then you would need to specify all of them. For example, if your service needs `$timeout`:

```
angular.module("fooModule", []).factory("FooSvc", function($timeout){
  ...
}
```

then you would need to inject it like so:

```
var fooSvcInstance = angular.injector(["fooModule", "ng"]).get("FooSvc");
```

Also, note that the instance of the service will be different than what will be injected into your app.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Us0mhEIe6Vz2MbNCzOi?p=preview)

You should re-evaluate *why* you need to do this.

**EDIT**

To get the same instance of the service as what the app gets you would need to get the same instance of the injector. To do that, you would need to object the `injector` from a DOM element in your Angular's app. For example, let's say that `<body>` is in your app:

```
// make sure that body has loaded (for example, in window.onload)
var injectorInstance = angular.element(document.body).injector();
var fooSvcInstance = injectorInstance.get("FooSvc");
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxBTYF7O8fELzG6YAJq1?p=preview)

Comment: The instance of the service would have to be the same, otherwise it misses the point for me. Is it possible?
Should I just use the same module as in my app?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay - yes, it's possible - you'd need to retrieve the injector from the element in the Angular's app DOM tree. I updated the answer.